# Block hover effect on anchor elements

Tags: html, css, anchor, effect

I want to add a block hover effect on my menu. However, the template that I bought has a large stylesheet that looks like it came out of Darth Vader's rear end - and my coding knowledge is limited making this task difficult.

Here is a fiddle of the menu part of my site (it contains the entire stylesheet as well): http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/

Upon hover, I want a block hover effect with each menu link having a different block color, see this picture as example (note that I want the block to be small when the mouse is not on it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aYeQ.png

I came across a script that does this.
HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Text">Link Heading One
        <em>Description of link.</em>
        <span>Date posted</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Text">Link Heading One
        <em>Description of link.</em>
        <span>Date posted</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#links li {
        border: 1px dotted #999;
        border-width: 1px 0;
        margin: 5px 0;
}

#links li a {
        color: #990000;
        display: block;
        font: bold 120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding: 5px;
        text-decoration: none;
}

 * html #links li a {  /* make hover effect work in IE */
    width: 400px;
}

#links li a:hover {
        background: #ffffcc;
}

#links a em {
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        font: normal 85% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 125%;
}

#links a span {
        color: #125F15;
        font: normal 70% Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 150%;
}
```

I read that hover only works in certain IE versions on anchor elements so I would presume that this technique is the best one to go with.

Now, how can I add this to my own page? Feel free to update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/
And please let me know if you would need any more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add border-bottom and background color on hover.

See this Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/enve/VjhJ4/7/

Comment: Excellent, how do I change the height size of the border-bottom?

Comment: Alright, I see now, allow me a minute to add this to my own site, I might have questions before I accept this as the correct answer. Cheers for the assistance.

Comment: Ok my friend, it worked perfectly. I have a few questions, I see that you used the **!important** CSS, how compatible is that? And is there any way that I skip using it and insert your code directly to where it is supposed to be? As !important overrides the existing style doesn't it?

Comment: Have you finished this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

to (changing the color to whatever color you actually want):

```
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; background-color:red; }
```

and change:

```
a { text-decoration: none; color: #00b7f3;}
```

to (changing the color to whatever color you actually want):

```
a { text-decoration: none; color: #00b7f3; border-bottom-color: red; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 5px;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KqaC8/

Edit: This will only do the hover color, working on the bottom color when not hovering, please hold.

Edit 2: This should do everything you want now.

Comment: How do I select different colours for each link?

Comment: If you could kindly give me instructions of how to do that, I can select this answer as the correct one as so far, it is doing what I requested. Missing the different colour feature though.

Comment: Also, can I set a height to the underline as well? I tried **border-bottom-height: 10px;** but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

[**see this DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/1/). you need to set the background color etc on hover

Comment: Can you please check the image that I posted: http://i.imgur.com/1xbbl.png I want there to be a type of line underneath it as well. And I need each link to have a different colour. Thank you for the respond regardless

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the CSS you in the template you have, you can do something like this...

```
li.menu-item:hover{background:red !important;}
```

The !important will just override the templates styles

Here is a fiddle that gives you some basic css.. you can still use !important to make sure it overrides your template code http://jsfiddle.net/cX5bk/

Comment: Does !important work on all browsers? And can you please demonstrate how I would do the underline as I demonstrated in my image: http://i.imgur.com/1xbbl.png

Comment: !important is part of the CSS1 spec... so  IE5.5+, Firefox 1+, Safari 3+, Chrome 1+. ...

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqpdI

Here's an example I made with what I believe you need. It's actually very simple, and there are many ways to do it! Basically each link (or it's parent) would need a class, and then you can change the colors for each class's  tag.

Comment: Wow that looks excellent, can you kindly try to add your script to my own so that I can see how it will work? My fiddle URL is: http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/

Comment: That is an excellent script, very clean. However if you read my question, you will see that my issue is with my own stylesheet, it is to big and to difficult for me to understand how to implement this script into it. This is why I suggest if you have the time to do it in the fiddle link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you do not understand much of CSS, and you buy a template, so you must not knowing much of it.

Thats okay, so before all people send you stuff and solutions that you don't understand, i updated your fiddle with the result like the picture you referring at:

[This is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/11/)

```
ul#secondary-menu a { font-size: 13px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px 0 16px; }

ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-33 a {border-bottom:5px solid #00f;}
ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-34 a {border-bottom:5px solid #0f0;}
ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-35 a {border-bottom:5px solid #f00;}

ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #fff;text-shadow: 0 0;}

ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-33 a:hover {background-color:#00f;}
ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-34 a:hover{background-color:#0f0;}
ul#secondary-menu #menu-item-35 a:hover{background-color:#f00;}
```

Comment: I am not completely in the dark to be honest, although last time I was coding something properly was late 90s when CSS was never used and font-size was my best friend ;) I will try your adjusted code in my main site. Can you please do a quick rundown of what exactly you added and if it will have any compatibility issues with browsers... e.g. where do I change the colours, where do I add more etc...

Comment: There a re no browser incompatibilities. search in the CSS for ul#secondary-menu a, i update my answer